# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate super slow when code on network drive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

My computer has Windows 7 installed.  When using VS2010 for a solution stored locally, it is really fast.  Design mode is totally responsive and has zero lag.  But when I open a solution that is stored on a network drive that is on the same network as me, I can barely use VS2010.  I can't even resize a window in design mode without the computer hanging.  The computer is brand new too: 6-core i7-3930K and 16 GB of RAM with an SSD.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because anything you do is being temporarily saved in files in your solution's directory.  This allows you do undo changes (CTRL-Z), and also helps in case the program crashes and you didn't save your project (It can recover what you were doing this way).

So basically, everytime you type something, resize something etc etc, each of those changes are being saved in your solutions folder on your network drive, which is much slower than your local hard disk.